# How to get all xml nodes and values

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing

I have an xml and want to get all the nodes and values from it. Below an example of the source xml and the output I want to create:

```
<bookstore>
  <book category="COOKING">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price curr="$">30.00</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>

Nodes   Values
bookstore.book.category COOKING
bookstore.book.title.lang   en
bookstore.book.title    Everyday Italian
bookstore.book.author   Giada De Laurentiis
bookstore.book.year 2005
bookstore.book.price.curr   $
bookstore.book.price    30
```

The output I want to create consists of 2 columns, nodes and it's value. How can I achieve this? Should I use XmlDocument class?

Comment: I don't see any XML at the moment... when you *do* have some XML, I'd suggest using LINQ to XML in general. You can use `Descendants()` to get all elements, then for each element you can construct a chain of names using `AncestorsAndSelf()`. I suggest you try with that much information, and include how far you've got in your question (along with the XML).

Comment: The source XML would definitely be beneficial because from the output, it doesn't look like it is valid XML.  I don't think the <title> node is allowed to have both a <lang> child and a text value (Everyday Italian).

Comment: Just posted the code you need. Please mark as answer if it works for you. It produces the exact same output you need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a recursive method that accepts a string containing the current path and the XmlNode to go into.  In each recursion it looks like you want to loop through all the node attributes and then each child node.  Check your NodeType to determine when you have reach the end of the recursion.

Load the original XML into an XmlDocument, then call your recursive method starting with the DocumentElement node.

**EDIT:**

Not the prettiest code I've ever done but it takes the given input and produces the requested output:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string xmlSrc = @"<bookstore><book category=""COOKING""><title lang=""en"">Everyday Italian</title><author>Giada De Laurentiis</author><year>2005</year><price curr=""$"">30.00</price></book></bookstore>";

    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.LoadXml(xmlSrc);

    StringBuilder sbOut = new StringBuilder();
    sbOut.AppendLine("Nodes\tValues");
    sbOut.Append(XmlToText(xDoc.DocumentElement));

    Console.WriteLine(sbOut.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}


static StringBuilder XmlToText(XmlElement node, string generationPath = "")
{
    StringBuilder sbRet = new StringBuilder();

    generationPath += (String.IsNullOrEmpty(generationPath) ? "" : ".") + node.Name;

    foreach( XmlAttribute attr in node.Attributes)
    {
        sbRet.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}.{1}\t{2}", generationPath, attr.Name, attr.Value));
    }

    foreach( XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        if( child.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            sbRet.Append(XmlToText(child as XmlElement, generationPath));
        }
        else if ( child.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        {
            sbRet.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}\t{1}", generationPath, child.InnerText));
        }
    }

    return sbRet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you are looking for

```
private static void PrintOutNodesRecursive(XmlElement xmlElement, string currentStack)
{
    foreach (XmlAttribute xmlAttribute in xmlElement.Attributes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1} = {2}", currentStack, xmlAttribute.Name, xmlAttribute.Value);
    }
    foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlElement.ChildNodes)
    {
        XmlElement xmlChildElement = xmlNode as XmlElement;
        XmlText xmlText = xmlNode as XmlText;

        if (xmlText != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", currentStack, xmlText.Value);
        }

        if (xmlChildElement != null)
        {
            PrintOutNodesRecursive(xmlChildElement, currentStack + "." + xmlChildElement.Name);
        }
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string xmlContent = @"<bookstore>
      <book category=""COOKING"">
        <title lang=""en"">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price curr=""$"">30.00</price>
      </book>
    </bookstore>";

    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlContent);

    PrintOutNodesRecursive(xmlDocument.DocumentElement, xmlDocument.DocumentElement.Name);

}
```